# Calling shell script inside shell script based on no of arguments passed to first script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

We are doing automation to databases where we have one script is calling another script in the shell. Forex :-

```
first-script.sh arg1 agr2 arg3 [Suppose 3 arguments are passed, then we have to call second-script.sh 3 times]
#!/bin/bash 
./second-script.sh $1 
./second-script.sh $2 
./second-script.sh $3
```

How can we remove this dependency? We want something like if 2 arguments are passed then automatically first script should run like

```
first-script.sh arg1 agr2
#!/bin/bash 
./second-script.sh $1 
./second-script.sh $2
```

and if 5 arguments are passed then, it should run like

```
first-script.sh arg1 agr2 arg3 arg4 arg5 
#!/bin/bash 
./second-script.sh $1 
./second-script.sh $2 
./second-script.sh $3
./second-script.sh $4 
./second-script.sh $5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "$@" (or possibly $*) to represent all the arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in "$@"
do
   ./second-script.sh "$arg"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to loop over the arguments.

```sh
for arg in $@  ; do 
    second-script.sh "$arg"
done
```

Comment: You for got to quote the variables.